# combobox on selected index changed only fires when press enter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hello as the title states my OnSelectedIndexChanged event only fires when you select the item then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. My combobox and gridview get their values from a datasource. OnSelectedIndexChanged the gridview filters but the combobox always has all the values. Any ideas why this happening?

asp

```
<asp:combobox ID="cbCustomer" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="dataSourceCBCust" DataTextField="CUST_NAME" DataValueField="CUST_NAME" MaxLength="0" 
    style="display: inline;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:combobox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCustomer" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cbCustomer" EventName ="SelectedIndexChanged" />   
    </Triggers>
       <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomer" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="dataSourceGVCust" 
                 AutoGenerateColumns="True" Visible="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">  
           </asp:GridView>  
       </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

vb

```
Protected Sub cbCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbCustomer.SelectedIndexChanged
     'do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: The `combobox` control appears to be a custom control. Is hard to tell what is causing the issue without looking into the code that implements the control.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I got the combobox from ajax toolkit if that helps any

Comment: Ok then, I've retagged you question with the `AjaxControlToolkit` tag.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I tried adding an event handler for both SelectedIndexChanged and TextChanged (which ComboBox has in common with DropDownList), but in either case nothing happens unless I press enter.

Comment: In my case, I wasn't explicitly setting AutoPostBack=true and when I did, this problem went away and the event fired when I selected anything from the dropdown of the ComboBox. I don't know why it's still happening for the above code example, which already has AutoPostBack=true.